# Cannot Dynamically Set Enum in Swift with Reflection

Tags: swift, objective-c, reflection, enums

I am attempting to dynamically clone a class object in Swift using reflection and the `setValue` function. This class contains an `enum` property that is backed with an `Int`, which is causing this dynamic reflection to crash:

```
@objc enum Status : Int {
    case green
    case yellow
    case red
}

@objc class State : NSObject {
    @objc var status : Status
    
    init(_ status: Status) {
        self.status = status
    }
}

func testReflectiveClone() {
    let state1 = State(.green)
    let state2 = State(.yellow)
    
    let state1Mirror = Mirror(reflecting: state1)
    
    for property in state1Mirror.children.enumerated() {
        let label = property.element.label
        state2.setValue(property.element.value, forKey: label!) //crashes here
    }
}
```

This test function is throwing the following error in XCode:

```
-[__SwiftValue longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001e5a340 (NSInvalidArgumentException)
```

Is it even possible to dynamically set enum values? What modification would I need to make to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add rawValue to avoid the runtime error.

```
state2.setValue(property.element.value.rawValue, forKey: label!)
```

Please check the definition of **setValue**.

```
open func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
```

The enum value you passed will be transferred to internal class named  "__SwiftValue", the compiler found that "status" was an Int enum type and tried to convert the value to Swift.Int with "longlongvalue", so the runtime error happened.